# How do I update my X axis header title on highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatables

I am using Datatables to create Highcharts. Everything functions as intended, however I am not sure how to extract the X axis title from Column 1. (Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5 etc.). I am not sure what am I missing in my code. Any advice would be appreciated because I don't know much about Javascript. Thanks in advance.

The chart should look like this.
See screenshot below.

[image]

Link to code - http://live.datatables.net/muvoyacu/2/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#example_full2").DataTable({
  searching:false,
lengthChange: false,
ordering: false,
info: false,
paging: false,

} );

    //var salary = getSalaries(table);

    var salary = getRow(table,0);
var salary2 = getRow(table, 1);
 var salary3 = getRow(table, 2);
  var salary4 = getRow(table, 3);
  var salary5 = getRow(table, 4);
 
  

 
    // Declare axis for the column graph
    var axis = {
        id: "salary",
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: "Number"
        }
    };
 
    // Declare inital series with the values from the getSalaries function
   var series = {
name: "2012",
data: Object.values(salary)
};
var series2 = {
name: "2013",
data: Object.values(salary2)
};
  var series3 = {
name: "2014",
data: Object.values(salary3)
};
  var series4 = {
name: "2015",
data: Object.values(salary4)
};
    var series5 = {
name: "2016",
data: Object.values(salary5)
};
 
 
   var myChart = Highcharts.chart("container", {
chart: {
type: "column"
},
title: {
text: "Test Data"
},
xAxis: {
categories: Object.keys(salary)
},
yAxis: axis,
series: [series, series2, series3, series4, series5]
    
});

// On draw, get updated salaries and refresh axis and series
table.on("draw", function() {
salary = getSalaries(table);
myChart.axes[0].categories = Object.keys(salary);
myChart.series[0].setData(Object.values(salary));
});
});

function getSalaries(table) {
var salaryCounts = {};
var salary = {};


}

function getRow(table, row) {
var chart = {};
var data = table.row(row).data();

for (i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
var x = $( table.column( i ).header() ).html();
var y = data[i].replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "") * 1;

chart[x] = y;
}
return chart;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />

  </head>
  <body>

<div id="container" style=" width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<div class="container">
<table id="example_full2" class="display nowrap" width="100%"><thead>
<tr><th>Year</th><th>2012</th><th>2013</th><th>2014</th><th>2015</th><th>2016</th><th>2017</th><th>2018</th><th>2019</th><th>2020</th><th>2021</th></tr></thead>
  
 <tr ><td> Data1</td><td>3,823</td><td>3,823</td><td>3,954</td><td>3,959</td><td>3,955</td><td>3,956</td><td>3,843</td><td>3,699</td><td>3,472</td><td>3,551</td></tr>
   <tr ><td> Data2</td><td>800</td><td>3,823</td><td>3,954</td><td>3,959</td><td>3,955</td><td>3,956</td><td>3,843</td><td>3,699</td><td>3,472</td><td>3,551</td></tr> 
   <tr ><td> Data3</td><td>900</td><td>3,823</td><td>3,954</td><td>3,959</td><td>3,955</td><td>3,956</td><td>3,843</td><td>3,699</td><td>3,472</td><td>3,551</td></tr> 
   <tr ><td> Data4</td><td>200</td><td>3,823</td><td>3,954</td><td>3,959</td><td>3,955</td><td>3,956</td><td>3,843</td><td>3,699</td><td>3,472</td><td>3,551</td></tr> 
   <tr ><td> Data5</td><td>300</td><td>3,823</td><td>3,954</td><td>3,959</td><td>3,955</td><td>3,956</td><td>3,843</td><td>3,699</td><td>3,472</td><td>3,551</td></tr> 
   <tr ><td> Data6</td><td>400</td><td>3,823</td><td>3,954</td><td>3,959</td><td>3,955</td><td>3,956</td><td>3,843</td><td>3,699</td><td>3,472</td><td>3,551</td></tr> 
  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Change this `<tr><th>Year</th><th>2012</th><th>2013</th><th>2014</th><th>2015</th><th>2016</th><th>2017</th><th>2018</th><th>2019</th><th>2020</th><th>2021</th></tr></thead>`
To this 
`<tr><th>Year</th><th>Data1</th><th>Data2</th><th>Data3</th><th>Data4</th><th>Data5</th><th>data6</th><th>data7</th><th>data8</th><th>data9</th><th>data10</th></tr></thead>`

Comment: Thanks, but I am not allowed to change the table headers. The table should remain same. The chart should pull X axis from column1.

Comment: You need to refactor your data parser or use Highcharts with its own parsing - which I recommend. Take a look at the following demo - you can use it in your project or base on it to reconstruct parsing: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b3hpungj/